# how to plot Market Profile with diffrent grayscale

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image][image]

The left figure is daily calendar bar. Diffrent day with diffrent grayscale value. I want to convert canlendar bar into Market Profile like the right figure. Any idea how to realize it? Just idea without code is also important to me.

Comment: Care to explain how the data on the left map to the histogram (?) on the right?